# Are people still researching the use of spectral decomposition on finite groups for data analysis?

Tags: references, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis

In A GENERALIZATION OF SPECTRAL ANALYSIS WITH APPLICATION TO RANKED DATA (Diaconis 1989), the author discusses a dataset of election results. There were 5 candidates, and each voter was asked to rank the candidates from most to least favorite. Diaconis treats the data as a function on $S_5$, and decomposes it using an inverse Fourier transform. He then uses the coefficients to infer some conclusions about the data (e.g. recognizing blocs of voters).

In chapter 8 of his book Group Representations in Probability and Statistics, Diaconis gives a few other examples of spectral analysis of various groups in statistics. Also he gives kind of a heuristic reason for why invariant subspaces might tell us something about data.

I am pretty interested in these ideas, but I can't seem to find many recent papers on the topic. I was wondering: are people still researching these topics, or are there better tools/alternatives out there now?

Book link: https://jdc.math.uwo.ca/M9140a-2012-summer/Diaconis.pdf

Paper link: https://jdc.math.uwo.ca/M9140a-2014-summer/Diaconis-1989.pdf